# В чем сбой?

Tags: c++

При отдельном коде, где часть с файлом, все работает. Набираю "u" ENTER и слово выводится на экран. А сейчас при нажатии любых клавиш, кроме U, без нажатия на ENTER слово выводится на экран, а при нажатии на U он даже не реагирует. В чем проблема?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct el {
    string data;
    el *adres;
};
class List {
  private:
    el * fadr, *eadr;

  public:
    List() {
        fadr = NULL;
        eadr = NULL;
    } void fadd(string a) {
        el *v;
        v = new el;
        v->data = a;
        v->adres = fadr;
        fadr = v;
    }

    void print() {
        if (fadr == NULL) {
            cout << "List is emptyn";
            return;
        }
        el *v;
        for (v = fadr; v != NULL; v = v->adres)
            cout << v->data << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ifstream input("c:\f.txt");
    string s;

    while (!input.eof()) {
        char v = getch();
       string s;            
        getline(input, s);
         if (v=='u')
        cout << s << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В том, что getch() работает не так, как Вы рассчитываете.

getch() читает символ с клавиатуры **без** ожидания ENTER. А не реагирует, так Вы сами *continue* написали.

Comment: я этот баг исправил. Просто помоги мне в следующем разобраться. У меня в файле 5 слов. Когда я нажимаю только на U, все идет отлично, выводит. Но бэг в следующем: Т.к там у меня 5 элементов, то он реагирует просто на все мои клавиши, и при 5 раз нажатии на любую клавишу, он без вывода ничего закрывается. Это тоже от getch зависит? Я исправил код.

Comment: while(!input.eof()) {
        char v = getch(); if (v != 'u') continue;
        getline(....
        ....
    }

Нет !!!

Абсолютно неправильно начинать обучение программированию с ЯВУ. Полгода блок-схем и бэйсика. Потом полгода на ассемблере.

Выжившие сами (для облегчения жизни себе любимому) что надо выучат.

Comment: Я вижу, что это кресты. ЯВУ это не обязательно JAVA. Аббревиатура ЯВУ означает Язык Высокого Уровня. Например C++, Python, JAVA, Ada, Pascal, PL/I и т.п.

Лично я предпочитаю Си, который (опять же лично я) к ЯВУ не отношу, считая его развитым макроассемблером с типами даных.

Comment: а не поможешь с бэгом?

Comment: Уже писал: 

while(!input.eof()) { char v = getch(); if (v **!= **'u') continue; getline(.... .... }

** v != 'u' **

Answer (score 2):

[@navi1893](/users/4969/navi1893), **внимательно посмотрите Ваш код !**

Вы ждете ввода любого символа. **Читаете строку**. Если введенный (**до чтения строки**) символ **равен 'u'** , то печатаете строку.

Все это повторяете в цикле, пока файл не кончится.

Что написали, то и видите.

--

Лучше **нормальным русским языком** подробно напишите, ЧТО Вы ХОТИТЕ. Этот текст называется "*функциональная спецификация*". Затем Вы **внимательно** читаете ее и сами **пишете код в соответствии с ней**.

И все у Вас получится.

Comment: ну да, я так и хочу. Если введенный (до чтения строки) символ равен 'u' , то печатает строку. Но почему он при любых остальных клавишах заканчивает работу? Я хочу чтобы он реагировал только на U, а остальные клавиши хоть миллион раз нажать, чтобы он не реагировал и не заканчивал работу свою.